# v-select rules not working after passing return-object props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I'm using vuetify in my project where I needed to use object in v-select. but `rules` prop is not working when I pass `return-object` props. If I remove `return-object` props then validation in `rules` prop works just fine. Here is what I am doing in template -

```
<v-select
     outlined
     v-model="role"
     label="Select Position*"
     :items="roleName"
     :rules="requiredField"
      return-object
      item-text="name"
      item-value="_id"
          />
```

and in my data I'm defining rules like this -
`requriedField: [v => !!v || "Field is required"]`

How can I set rules for object type in v-select?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by checking empty objects. In rules I changed my validation rule with this

```
[v => Boolean(Object.keys(v || {})[0]) || "Field is required"]
```